# convert string integor with commas and dot to float

Tags: python

Hello I need some help writing a function to convert string representation of price to actual float

```
values = ['1.999,00','299,00','299,86', '1.549,99']
```

ideally the output would be

```
output = [1999.00, 299.00, 299.86, 1549.99]
```

I tried to do it using `replace` but couldn't get it done.

Comment: _"I tried to do it using replace but couldn't get it done."_ Show what you did and what failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative method is;

```
values = ['1.999,00','299,00','299,86', '1.549,99']
values = [float(value.translate(str.maketrans({'.': '', ',': '.'}))) for value in values]
```

This is the output:

```
print(values)
[1999.0, 299.0, 299.86, 1549.99]
```

maketrans is an elegant way to swap values of two variable with each other simultaneously, for instance A, B = B, A

Answer (score 1):

hayo, first replace the dot with nothing, then replace `,` with `.`.

```
values = ["1.999,00", "299,00", "299,86", "1.549,99"]

output = [float(x.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) for x in values]

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things you appear to be dealing with Euro formatting.
For simplicity, we'll go back to English. with that, swap dots with nothing and commas with dots. Have a new list to push floats to after conversion.

```py
    values = ['1.999,00','299,00','299,86', '1.549,99']
    floatValues = []
    
    for v in values:
        tmp = v.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")
        floatValues.append(float(tmp))
    
    
    print ("values: ", values);
    print ("floatValues: ", floatValues);
```

***Output***

```
values:  ['1.999,00', '299,00', '299,86', '1.549,99']

floatValues:  [1999.0, 299.0, 299.86, 1549.99]
```

Comment: exactly correct, I am converting Euro to USD